# How do I search for a file/open/create a googlesheet in another users folder using a service account?

Tags: java, selenium, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Here is the scenario.  I have an account where I keep test result spreadsheets.  I have a service account that I use to programatically (with java and google drive apiv3) to add/update those spreadsheets.  I need a way to create a spreadsheet and to search for a spreadsheet in that users account and folder from the service account.  I have the following code which gets a list of files, however it's the files inside the service accounts folder, not the user accounts folder.  Any help?

```
private static boolean findSpreadsheetFile(String sSpreadsheetName)
                throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    String pageToken = null;
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive driveService = getDriveService();
    // Print the names and IDs
    do
    {
        FileList result = driveService.files().list()
                        .setPageToken(pageToken)
                        .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                        .execute();
        for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : result.getFiles())
        {
            System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
        }
        pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
    }
    while (pageToken != null);
    return true;
}

public static Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    Credential credential = authorizeDrive();
    return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}

private static GoogleCredential authorizeDrive() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    URL fileUrl = ParseTestResultsEmails.class.getResource(sP12Filename);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setServiceAccountId(sServiceAccountID)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(fileUrl.toURI()))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(DRIVE_SCOPES).build();
    return credential;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if there is no way to do what I wanted in Google Drive using the API.  What I ended up doing, was creating the sheet as the "Service Account", then transferring ownership to the user I wanted, then could share it to the groups that needed access.  That worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority), domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0 to delegate authority this way.

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In G Suite domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority.
>
> **Warning:** Service accounts should only be used for performing delegation where the effective identity is that of an individual user in a domain. Using the service account as a common owner to create many shared documents can have severe performance implications. Additionally, service accounts may not acquire additional storage quota, nor do they act as members of a domain.

You may see the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) documentation for more information.

Comment: We do not use GSuite domains.  Nor am I a domain Admin.  Unfortunately, this will not work.